# Java API for kafka-acls.sh in kerberised environment?

Tags: security, apache-kafka, kerberos, java

I am using hdp 2.4 kerberised.
I am creating topic dynamically through java API.
Its getting created successfully, but can some one help to give access for all user,as we does by using kafka-acls.sh.

just wanted to run below command through java:

```
kafka-acls.sh --add --allow-principals user:ctadmin --operation ALL --topic marchTesting --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect={hostname}:2181
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple:

```
import kafka.admin.AclCommand;    

String[] cmdPArm = {"--add", "--allow-principals", "user:ctadmin", "--operation", "ALL","--topic", topicName ,"--authorizer-properties", "zookeeper.connect=hscale-dev1-dn1:2181,hscale-dev1-dn3:2181,hscale-dev1-dn2:2181"};
AclCommand.main(cmdPArm);
```